# Detecting the current page from an included page

Tags: php

In my pages I have a top navigation bar.
I used to have this in the pages themselves but I've decided its better practice to have it in a seperate header file and then include this in every page.
The trouble is this has somewhat ruined my if server php self is whatever.php then class=current page on the nav bar.

Is there a way to detect the current page from within a header?

Comment: should work exactly the same way, an included file works as if you copy and pasted the contents in to the other file

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use:

```
basename(__FILE__);
```

This will return the name current script that is being executed.

Without the extension:

```
substr(basename(__FILE__), 0, -4);
```

Answer (score 0):

the way I found to do it was in my main page itself to set a variable

```
$current="whatever";
```

just before I run the header and then in the header check against the current variable